# How to list public albums and photos from Google Photos with PHP (migrating from Picasa)

Tags: php, api, photo

The problem: I can't find any example about access public albums and photos with Google Photos API using PHP. I don't want to log in user with google, no need upload files, I would like just display a user's albums, and photoes with custom design my site. Is there similar solution as Picasa API was?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not look like this is possible:

[see:](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/overview)

> Note that the Library API does not support service accounts; to use
>   this API, users must be signed in to a valid Google Account.

Comment: Thanks, I found same results. I'll moving albums to another image hosting service.